# Pygame Video Flickering

Tags: python, video, pygame

I have been playing with displaying videos on pygame and I found that my videos are flickering a lot with the following code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

FPS = 60

resolution = (240, 160)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mixer.quit()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)

surface = pygame.Surface(resolution).convert()

movie1Playing = True
movie2Playing = False
playedEarly = False
frames = 0
earlyCounter = 0

movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie1.mpg')
movie.set_display(screen)

movie.play()
movie.set_volume(0.5)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            movie.stop()
            raise SystemExit
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                if frames > 300 and movie1Playing:
                    movie.stop()
                    playedEarly = True
                    movie1Playing = False
                    movie2Playing = True
                    movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie2.mpg')
                    movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie2.mpg')
                    surface = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()
                    movie.set_display(surface)
                    movie.play()
                    movie.set_volume(0)
                    frames = 0
                elif movie2Playing:
                    raise SystemExit

    if movie.get_busy() == 0:
        if movie1Playing == True:
            movie.stop()
            movie1Playing = False
            movie2Playing = True
            movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie2.mpg')
            movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie2.mpg')
            surface = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()
            movie.set_display(surface)
            movie.play()
            movie.set_volume(0.5)
            frames = 0
        else:
            movie.stop()
            movie1Playing = True
            movie2Playing = False
            movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie1.mpg')
            movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie1.mpg')
            surface = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size())
            movie.set_display(surface)
            movie.play()
            movie.set_volume(0.5)
            frames = 0

    if playedEarly:
        earlyCounter += 1
        if earlyCounter > 67:
            movie.set_volume(0.5)
            playedEarly = False
            earlyCounter = 0
    frames += 1

    screen.blit(surface,(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

I have tried removing the blit and the pygame.display.flip() methods and this seems to reduce the flickering, however a second video is supposed to play immediately after the first one and if those are removed the second video does not play at all. Any help is appreciated!

!!EDIT!!

The video actually does play correctly anytime after the first video is done playing. For example, if I let the first video play through or skip it then the second video plays flawlessly and when it loops back around to playing the first video again then that video also plays flawlessly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just solved my own question for those of you struggling with this same thing. It seems that pygame needs to have the threat of quitting hung over it's head the entire time it's running. What I mean by that is that instead of invoking "raise SystemExit" I should've instead called pygame.quit(). Here's the cleaned code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

FPS = 60

#Scales
GAMEBOY         = 1        #240x160  (Standard gameboy resolution)
FOUREIGHTYP     = 2        #480x320  (480p resolution)
SEVENTWENTYP    = 4        #960x640  (720p resolution)
TENEIGHTYP      = 6        #1440x960 (1080p resolution)

scale = GAMEBOY

resolution = (240*scale, 160*scale)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mixer.quit()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)

surface = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()

#Gamestates
introsequence = 1
mainmenu      = 2

def introsequence(screen, surface):
    movie1Playing = True
    movie2Playing = False
    playedEarly = False
    frames = 0
    earlyCounter = 0

    movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie1.mpg')
    movie.set_display(surface)
    movie.play()
    movie.set_volume(0.5)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                movie.stop()
                pygame.quit()   #<---- Here
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    if frames > 300 and movie1Playing:
                        movie.stop()
                        playedEarly = True
                        movie1Playing = False
                        movie2Playing = True
                        movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie2.mpg')
                        movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie2.mpg')
                        surface = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()
                        movie.set_display(surface)
                        movie.play()
                        movie.set_volume(0)
                        frames = 0
                    elif movie2Playing:
                        pygame.quit()    #<----- Here

        if movie.get_busy() == 0:
            if movie1Playing == True:
                movie.stop()
                movie1Playing = False
                movie2Playing = True
                movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie2.mpg')
                movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie2.mpg')
                surface = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()
                movie.set_display(surface)
                movie.play()
                movie.set_volume(0.5)
                frames = 0
            else:
                movie.stop()
                movie1Playing = True
                movie2Playing = False
                movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie1.mpg')
                movie = pygame.movie.Movie('./intromovie1.mpg')
                surface = pygame.Surface(movie.get_size()).convert()
                movie.set_display(surface)
                movie.play()
                movie.set_volume(0.5)
                frames = 0

        if playedEarly:
            earlyCounter += 1
            if earlyCounter > 67:
                movie.set_volume(0.5)
                playedEarly = False
                earlyCounter = 0
        frames += 1

        screen.blit(surface,(0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)



def mainMenu(screen, surface):
    pass

def main(screen, surface):
    currentGamestate = introsequence
    pygame.mixer.quit()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()         #<---- and here

        if currentGamestate == introsequence:
            introsequence(screen, surface)
        else:
            pygame.mixer.init()
            if currentGamestate == mainmenu:
                mainMenu(screen, surface)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(screen, surface)
```

Hope this helps a few people! Happy coding!